# Verify selected dropdown by value in Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm selecting drop-down option by value using following code

```
SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(Base.driver.FindElement(by));
selectElement.SelectByValue(value);
```

Now, I want check if it selected correct option. But, the problem is I don't have text to verify like this

```
Assert.IsTrue(elem.SelectedOption.Text.Equals(name));
```

Is there anyway to do assert based on value of the selected option?

Comment: Could you use ToString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the selected element you can use the following:

```
var selectedValue = selectElement.SelectedOption.GetAttribute("value");
Assert.AreEqual(name, selectedValue);
```